# make a shake in css last for only 5 seconds in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a code which **displays an image** in class **dispbox**,  when user **clicks on** dispbox a **backgroundimage is added to body** and it **shakes**.

I have done the **click function** in **jquery** to start the shake in **css**.

**I want the shake to last for 5 seconds only.**

In my code the shake happens **neverending** and whenever i **hover**  on the background image

**How to change my code for making the shake last for only five seconds. and remove the hover from it**

```js
$("#dispbox").click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

html {
  background: red;
}

.dispbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.dispboximg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.shake {
  transform-origin: center center;
  ;
}

.shake:hover {
  animation: shake-base 100ms infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="dispbox" id="dispbox" style="border:none;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=20;" id="dispboximg" style="border:none;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `infinite` from the animation and add `5s` (duration)

Try this

```js
$("#dispbox").click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

html {
  background: red;
}

.dispbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.dispboximg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.shake {
  transform-origin: center center;
  ;
}

.shake:hover {
  animation: shake-base 5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="dispbox" id="dispbox" style="border:none;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=20;" id="dispboximg" style="border:none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: when i agin mouseover the backgroundimage it again shakes how to remove this mouse over effect?

Comment: You can use javascript for that

Answer (score 1):

> Use this animation: shake-base 1s;

Change the to 5s if you want it to shake for 5 seconds.

```js
$("#dispbox").click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('image').addClass('shake');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Basic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

html {
  background: red;
}

.dispbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.dispboximg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.shake { transform-origin: center center; animation: shake-base 0.5s ease-in-out; }

@keyframes shake-base {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  4% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  6% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  8% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  14% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  16% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  18% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  28% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  34% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  38% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  44% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  54% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  56% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  58% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  64% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  68% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  74% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  84% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg);
  }
  86% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, 0.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  88% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: translate(-1.5px, 1.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  94% {
    transform: translate(-0.5px, 0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(1.5px, -2.5px) rotate(0.5deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -0.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="dispbox" id="dispbox" style="border:none;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=20;" id="dispboximg" style="border:none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: when clicking on image it shakes for 5 seconds that woks,  but when when i agin mouseover the backgroundimage it again shakes how to remove this mouse over effect?

Comment: It is occurring because you have .shake:hover { }

Remove it.

Check the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
.shake:hover {
  animation: shake-base 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Just change '100ms infinite' to '5s' in value of animation property.

Comment: thank you for the solution,  is there a way i can remove the hover effect also, becoz when i mouseover on backgroundimage it still shakes.. how to remove it

Comment: Can you please clarify what actually you requires? Do you need when image get occurs only at that time it should shake ? Remove .shake:hover css and modify shake class css.
.shake {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: shake-base 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: thank for reply, i will explain,  i need backgroundimage shake only when i click the first image shown.  but when i move the cursor on th background image it still shakes i want to remove that property

Comment: Please follow the instruction that I have maintained in above comment.